# I want to find the date that corresponds to X months from now (Excel)

Tags: excel

I have a cell containing the number X, the number of months. I want to have, in another cell, an equation that uses X and returns the date that corresponds to X months ahead of, say, today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With X in A1, pick another cell and enter:

**=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+A1,DAY(TODAY()))**

Comment: Hi punts:  Although counter-intuitive, this behavior is correct!

Comment: Hi pnuts:  Post an alternative and we can discuss the pros and cons..........

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `EDATE` which does specifically as required, i.e.

`=EDATE(TODAY,A1)`

results can differ between that version and Gary's Student's version when the day of the month is >=29 and that day doesn't exist in the "target" month [as per pnuts' comment] - E.g. if today is 31st October 2013 and A1 = 4 then the EDATE formula will return 28th February 2014 but GS's will give you 3rd March 2014.

In Excel 2003 EDATE requires Analysis ToolPak add-in but in later versions of Excel it's a built-in function